# Find Rscript.exe on Windows

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to execute Rscript on a windows computer. For this, I need to find the exact location of Rscript, since it is not on %PATH%. Searching stackoverflow, I found this approach

```
where /r "c:\Program Files" Rscript.exe
```

which produces three lines:

```
c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\Rscript.exe
c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\i386\Rscript.exe
c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe
```

Now I do not know how to proceed. How can I assign one of the three lines to a (local) environment variable in windows cmd? Ideally, it would be the first or third line, i.e. the x64 rscript.exe.

Another approach I found on SO is like this:

```
set "src=c:\Program Files"
set "search=Rscript.exe"

for /r "%src%" %%F in (*%search%*) do (
  set "full=%%~fF"
  set "name=%%~nxF"
  echo %full%
)
```

but somehow nothing gets assigned to %full%.

Since I would like to run the batch file on more than one computer, I would like to avoid doing extra configuration on these computers (like setting PATH or R_HOME or assigning Rscript to .R files or...)

Comment: Your code just lacks [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (when you replace `echo %full` by `set full` you will notice that the variable is actually set; using `echo !full!` with delayed expansion enabled would work too)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first advice I'd offer, is that you check to see if its location was added to the registry under the file association with `.RData` files. If found, you could essentially replace `RGui.exe` with `RScript.exe`:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Classes\RWorkspace\Shell\Open\Command"
Set "RDir="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "%Key%" /VE 2^>NUL'
) Do Set "RDir=%~dpH"
If Not Defined RDir For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "HKLM%Key:~4%" /VE 2^>NUL') Do Set "RDir=%~dpH"
If Defined RDir Where /Q "%RDir%.":"RScript.exe" && (
    Set "RDir=%RDir%RScript.exe") || Set "RDir="
If Defined RDir Echo Your default RScript.exe absolute path is %RDir% & Pause
```

Other alternatives would be to check the registry uninstall information for the install location, and if found, append the `\bin` subdirectory and its respective architecture child:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Set "Sub=R for Windows"
Set "Val=InstallLocation"
Set "Reg=%__AppDir__%reg.exe"
Set "Find=%__AppDir__%find.exe"
Set "RDir="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In (
    '"%Reg% Query "%Key%" /S /F "%Sub%" /K /V "%Val%" 2>NUL|%Find% "\""'
) Do Set "RDir=%%H"
If Not Defined RDir If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In (
        '"%Reg% Query "%Key%" /S /F "%Sub%" /K /V "%Val%" /Reg:32 2>NUL|%Find% "\""'
    ) Do Set "RDir=%%H")
If Not Defined RDir GoTo :EOF
If "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%" == "86" (
    If Not Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\i386"
) Else Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\x64") Else Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\x64"
Where /Q "%RDir%":"RScript.exe" && (Set "RDir=%RDir%\RScript.exe") || Set "RDir="
If Defined RDir Echo Your default RScript.exe absolute path is %RDir% & Pause
```

It may also be worth checking to see if the installation option to `Save version number in registry` was selected under `Select Additional Tasks` at installation time, *(or later using `RSetReg.exe` or `RSetReg.exe /Personal`)*, then using the home directory path returned to append your subdirectories:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Reg=%__AppDir__%reg.exe"
Set "Find=%__AppDir__%find.exe"
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\R-core\R"
Set "Val=InstallPath"
Set "RDir="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In (
    '"%Reg% Query "%Key%" /S /F "%Val%" /V 2>NUL|%Find% "\""') Do Set "RDir=%%~H"
If Not Defined RDir For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In (
    '"%Reg% Query "HKLM%Key:~4%" /S /F "%Val%" /V 2>NUL|%Find% "\""'
) Do Set "RDir=%%~H"
If Not Defined RDir GoTo :EOF
If "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%" == "86" (
    If Not Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\i386"
) Else Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\x64") Else Set "RDir=%RDir%\bin\x64"
Where /Q "%RDir%":"RScript.exe" && (Set "RDir=%RDir%\RScript.exe") || Set "RDir="
If Defined RDir Echo Your default RScript.exe absolute path is %RDir% & Pause
```

It would only be if one of those methods failed to provide a location, would I consider performing a search of the system drive, or possibly other available volumes for an executable file.

Answer (score 2):

Command output can be captured into a variable using a for /F loop. If conditions or piping the output into find or findstr can further filter that output.

For a simple case of capturing just the first line of output, the below should suffice.

```bat
@echo off
Setlocal ENABLEdelayedexpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%0 In ('where /r "c:\Program Files" Rscript.exe') do If "!scriptpath!" == "" Set "scriptpath=%%~0"
```

Comment: Thanks! I would not have figured out to put the where statement in the braces..

Comment: I redirected the accept vote to @Compo since it may be the most useful for those with a similar question/task as I had. I learned much from your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is the solution I came up with:

```
@echo off

set "rscript=I:\path\to\myscript.R"

for /r "c:\Program Files" %%F in (*Rscript.exe*) do (
  "%%~fF" "%rscript%" %*
  goto :eof
)

echo No Rscript.exe found. Maybe you need to install R.
pause
```

EDIT: using the suggestions of @Compo, I modified the batch file thus:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

set "rscript=I:\path\to\myscript.R"

For /F "EOL=H Tokens=3*" %%G In (
    '"reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S /F "R for Windows" /K /V "InstallLocation" 2> NUL | find "InstallLocation""'
) Do Set "rexe=%%G %%Hbin\x64\Rscript.exe"

if not defined rexe goto nope

"%rexe%" "%rscript%" %*
goto :eof

:nope
echo No Rscript.exe found. Maybe you need to install R.
pause
```

Here some notes I learned along the way.

- `.RData` is associated to RStudio on my pc -- so not a good idea to look here.
- `SetLocal EnableExtension` is not necessary on my pc, but it may be on other pc, hence I kept the line
- The `Tokens=3*` defines `%G` as the third token and implicitly `%H` as all tokens after the third token. Crazy syntax.
- `2> NUL` means "ignore error messages"
- The double quotation `"'reg ...'"` is really necessary, I wonder why

This works for me now. I can be sure that the pc the batch file will run on are x64 architectures and are installed under `Program Files`.
Maybe later I need to add options to rscript. Also, I will have to figure out to use the latest R version in case there are more than one installed.